# How to write unit test for SpringBoot API having Spring Security configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I have created a **Spring Boot** application containing various endpoints. Except for `signup` and login endpoints I've added a filter for other requests. All other requests should have:

`Authorization`  `Bearer <token>`

and requests goes through Spring Security filter chain which checks the user exists in the table or not via `UserDetailService`.

I would like to know how can I write unit tests for any GET/POST  API with Spring Security in place ?

One way i have in mind is to generate the actual token by calling `signup` API and then call other APIs with the Authorization token generated by Signup API.

OR

There might be some way to mock or skip the Authorization Bearer for unit tests

I wanted to know what is this the correct/best approach that's followed across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my applications i have been using a conbination of `MockUser` annotation with a `MockMvc` bean. `MockUser` is able to populate Spring SecurityContext with a user and his principal, which includes his `User` object and `GrantedAuthority` (aka ROLEs). With this you can test your controllers without needing to create any token. It is easier and more decoupled from your autthentication process.

Like this:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser("admin")  
void testAuthorize() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/objects")).andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

In Spring docs you can read more [about](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser). And you also have [@WithAnonymousUser](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withanonymoususer), to simulate anonnymouser, [@WithUserDetails](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withuserdetails) to put a custom `UserDetailsService`.